# Highcharts xaxis start from 0

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the following Highchart:
[image: Current Chart]

I want to start the dates from the 1st point at 0,0 so that it looks like this:
[image]

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/87230rms/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/variwide.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

JS:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  yAxis: {
    min: 0
  },

  xAxis: [
    {
      categories: ["01-23", "02-23", "03-23", "04-23"]
    }
  ],    

  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },

  series: [
    {
      data: [10, 20, 30, 40]
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
series: [
    {
        data: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        pointPlacement: 'on' //Added this
    }
]
```

reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointPlacement

Comment: please explain your answer